# SQL Server : row_number over primary key

Tags: sql-server, insert, row-number

Is there any way to create `column` that will be increased and reset over primary key?

Example:

Table A ([Code], [Type], [Line No_])

Primary key is `([Code], [Type])`

And when I add a new row, I want to auto generate `[Line No_]` like this:

```
Code   Type   Line No_
-----------------------
'U1'     0     1000
'U1'     0     2000
'U1'     1     1000
```

Something like `ROW_NUMBER` but auto generated on insert row

Comment: You could probably do something like that with an `Insert` trigger.  What problem are you actually trying to solve here?

Comment: I have to sort the rows in order of creation but the user can change it any time.

Comment: This is pretty simple...until..."the user can change it any time". What does that mean? Your end user can reorder the data when they want to? Is there a reason that the numbering is by 1,000 each time? Can you just use row_number to set the original value? After that it would be up the user to decide the order right?

Comment: The user try to add few rows in some order i want to auto generate [Line No_] value by primary key. Numbering by 1000 is for the case when the user adds a row and change it's position e.g. add row1, row2, row3 but he decide to move row 3 before row 2 so i don't need to update row 2 and next rows but i can change [Line No_] value in row 3 to 1500. When i get rows ordered by [Line No_] i'll get row 1([Line No_]=1000), row 3 ([Line No_]=1500) and row 2 ([Line No_]=2000) etc.. 
If there is no way to create it like IDENTITY(1000,1000) OVER Primary Key so i think that i need to get this from user

Comment: I think you are way over thinking this. Use row_number to generate the initial values. Forget about the silliness of leaving gaps. It is pretty simple. If you have 100 rows and a user wants to insert a new row at 34 you simply update all rows setting SortOrder = SortOrder + 1 where SortOrder >= 34. Then insert the new row with SortOrder 34. Keep it simple.

Comment: I think that you have right. I'll do that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use a window function in a computed column. Computed columns must be scalar values. However, this is a perfect use case for a view.

[**See the DB Fiddle For the Code Below**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=71c4fdaee13719e4fccbb8f29216c9ce)

```
create table myTable ([Code] varchar(20),[Type] int)
go

insert into myTable
values
('U1',0)
,('U1',0)
,('U1',1)
go

create view MyView 
as
select *
    ,Line_No = row_number() over (partition by [Code], [Type] order by (select null)) * 1000
from myTable
go

select * from myView
```

Comment: This is not excacly what i need to achive. I have to sort the rows in order of creation but the user can change it any time. In this case this view is ordered by [Code], [Type] and it will never change.

Comment: What do you mean sort the rows in order of creation? Data is only stored "in order" based off the clustered index. Otherwise, the dataset is UNORDERED unless you specify an order by

Comment: So when the user adds row 1 ('U1', 0,'CPU','i7 XXXX') it need to [Line No_] = 1000 
Then he adds row 2 ('U1', 0,'GPU','GTX XXXX') and [Line No_] = 2000 
Then he adds row 3 ('U1', 1,'something','something') and [Line No_] = 1000

Comment: yes... the view will do that... and if a row is deleted, the the numbers will change

Comment: yes in this case it will be ok but when i adds row 1 ('U1', 0,'GPU','GTX XXXX') that need to be [Line No_] = 1000, row 2 ('U1', 0,'CPU','i7 XXXX') with [Line No_] = 2000 i'll recieve aplhabetical order not by [Line No_]. 
Probably i need get this value from user before insert it to the table.
Thank You for your time.

Comment: Then you can use `row_number() over (partition by [Code], [Type] order by[Code], [Type])` but the same rule applies.